# Access to Spring Test Class Object From Spring Context

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations

Weird subjects continue with the question itself :) is there any way to reach the spring test class from spring application context? Question details is hidden in the "SimpleDaoHandler" class as comment block :)

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext-core.xml")
public class DbFuntionTests {

    @TestAnnotation
    private UserSessionDao userSessionDao; 

    @Test
    public void testOracleTimestamp() throws Exception {
        userSessionDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

A handler class after the initialization of spring context:

```
@Component
public class SimpleDaoHandler implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleDaoHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        //I have the application context now, via method "setApplicationContext"
        // and need to get test class object to get the
        // annotated field "TestAnnotation" because I also need to set this
        // field with my business logic, using reflection.
        // Problem is; test class object is not included in the
        // "applicationContext" as a bean and I don't know how to access my 
        //test class which is already starting the spring context initialization. 
        //I need to get that test class object.
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be better to create some [post processor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9776071/577812) working with your `@TestAnnotation` ?  You can take a look at Spring `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` that scan beans having fields/methods annotated with `@Autowire` and processing them. I think that's something you try to achieve and bean post processor is the cleanest possible solution for such problems (used by the Spring itself).

Please look at the example below - the `MyAnnotationPostProcessor` scans for `MyAnnotation` on each bean within the application context and logs applicable fields. (of course instead of logging you can take some action ;)). Please be careful that your annotation must have `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` declared; otherwise, it would not be visible at the runtime.

```
public final class MyAnnotationPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyAnnotationPostProcessor.class);

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        final Set<Field> annotatedFields = getAnnotatedFields(bean.getClass());
        for (Field annotatedField : annotatedFields) {
            LOG.info("Post process before initialization " + beanName + "," + annotatedField);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        final Set<Field> annotatedFields = getAnnotatedFields(bean.getClass());
        for (Field annotatedField : annotatedFields) {
            LOG.info("Post process after initialization " + beanName + "," + annotatedField);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    private Set<Field> getAnnotatedFields(final Class<?> clazz) {
        final Set<Field> annotatedFields = new HashSet<Field>();
        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(hasMyAnnotation(field)) {
                annotatedFields.add(field);
            }
        }
        return annotatedFields;
    }

    private boolean hasMyAnnotation(final AccessibleObject ao) {
        return AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(ao, MyAnnotation.class) != null;
    }
}
```

Test class and annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MySpringTest {

    @MyAnnotation
    private UserSessionDAO dao;

    @Configuration
    static class TestContext {
        @Bean
        public static MyAnnotationPostProcessor myAnnotationPostProcessor() {
            return new MyAnnotationPostProcessor();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}

@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

Comment: You are right, some how @Autowired and AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor can do this but I find the code too much complex for my need(is it too obvious that i find difficult to understand that code? :)). Any way, your answer lead me to try different kind of post processors, if I get any result, I will inform you. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yeah, it looks complex, but only because it implements some autowiring logic - not because of @Autowired annotation lookup ;) Please find and updated answer - I've given example of simple post processor working with custom annotation.

Comment: Your answer is more detailed, so I have chosen your answer before mine :) viewers can also find my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Piotrek De, I finally found the answer. Your annotation handler class must also implement BeanPostProcessor class. This way, you get two methods that used by the test application context as well:

```
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    try {
        injectGDao(bean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BeanInstantiationException(bean.getClass(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    try {
        injectGDao(bean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BeanInstantiationException(bean.getClass(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
    return bean;
}
```

Whenever the test context listener reach this method, you can now reach the test class object. More detailed answer can be found at Piotrek De's answer as I mentioned before.